# Integrate sendbird with Angular6

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6, sendbird

I'm new to angular6 & nodejs. I'm trying to integrate sendbird with Angular6 but not getting any clear idea, how to start and where to start.

Anyone done this before can guide me?

P.S. I have called sendbird api in python.

Comment: sendbird Javascript SDK available. https://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-JavaScript

Comment: yes I checked that. Thank you.
Actually their example is nodejs based.
This is my first project and I have created one project for anguar & nodejs.so bit confused how can I use that code in nodejs.
Also I have added sendbird package in angular so looking for guide or sample to integrate in angular6

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya - Please post your comment as answer as I did same thing when I didnt foud any option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sendbird Javascript SDK available. http://github.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK-JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Currently, SendBird doesn't have the Angular guide.  We will provide it in the future.  Thanks for your interest!